# Swift.Bool isn't a Bool?

Tags: swift, types

I had a function

```
func login<Bool> (parameters: [(String, Any)],
                  completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    //Do something
}
```

And whenever I called the completion handler like so

```
completion(false)
```

or

```
completion(true)
```

XCode kept telling me: "Cannot convert value of type 'Swift.Bool' to expected argument type 'Bool'"

Eventually, I removed the  at the beginning of the function, and the error went away. I thought that  was declaring the type for the function, but I'm frankly not sure what that means, or what <> does despite googling. I'm sure it's explained well, but I'm not grasping the concept from googling alone. And why is Swift.Bool not able to be converted to Bool. I was able to find that there is an objective C version of bool and I thought maybe it was asking for that, but that didn't work either. What does that mean a Bool is?

Comment: By typing <Bool> you declared a generic constraint that overrode Swift.Bool. If you want to understand what <> do, lookup generics.

Comment: I suspect you have your own custom type also named `Bool`. If you command+click on the `Bool` of `completion`'s input, and may see the definition of your custom `Bool` type. Edit: seems you have edited your question, but never mind it's already answered ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax `func login<Bool>` defines a type parameter called `Bool`. It has nothing to do with `Swift.Bool`. It's just a name you've defined. It's the same as if you declared a local variable `var Bool: String`. You'd have a variable named `Bool` that is actually a String. Don't do that.

If you want the value to always be Bool, remove the type parameter. This isn't generic.

```
func login(parameters: [(String, Any)],
           completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
```

For details on the `<...>` syntax and generics see [Generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html) in The Swift Programming Language.

Comment: Hey Rob, that was a lot more simple and concise of an answer than I expected, been scratching my head at this for a while. Thank you for the explanation and help. I'll look into generics more, I've been trying to figure them out lately.

Comment: @Timothy You should accept Rob's answer as soon as you are allowed to. It's excellent as usual (voted).  And once you have enough reputation, consider up-voting high quality answers like this one.

Comment: I've just done that. I have the misfortune of not quite knowing how to ask good questions yet so my reputation is a bit stagnant, but that's the goal. Thank you for the advice Duncan. I feel very lucky to have access to this platform.